# GTK3 render text in TreeView for RTL languages like Hebrew

Tags: python-2.7, gtk3

I am trying to render text in the TreeView for Hebrew Language.

Since the Hebrew text is from RTL (Right to Left Language) I am using a marker '\u200f' to make the text appear from right to left.

Below is the code where I am trying to render the Hebrew text

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Pango

class CellRendererTextWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="CellRendererText Example")

        self.set_default_size(200, 200)
        a = u'\u200f\u202b<span float="right" foreground="black">\u05d1\u05d5\u05d0\u05d5 \u05d9\u05d7\u05d3 \u05d0\u05e8\u05d5\u05d7\u05ea \u05e6\u05d4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d9\u05dd</span>\u202c'
        self.liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str, str)

        treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.liststore)

        renderer_text = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        #renderer_text.set_property("xalign", 1.0)
        #renderer_text.set_property("ellipsize", Pango.EllipsizeMode.START)


        column_text = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Text", renderer_text, text=0)
        treeview.append_column(column_text)

        renderer_editabletext = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        renderer_editabletext.set_property("editable", True)

        column_editabletext = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Editable Text",
            renderer_editabletext, text=1)
        treeview.append_column(column_editabletext)

        renderer_editabletext.connect("edited", self.text_edited)

        textview = Gtk.TextView()
        textbuffer = textview.get_buffer()
        textbuffer.set_text(a)

        self.liststore.append(["Test", a])
        self.liststore.append([a, "http://fedoraproject.org/"])
        self.liststore.append(["Slackware"*10, "http://www.slackware.com/"])
        self.liststore.append(["Sidux", "http://sidux.com/"])

        self.add(treeview)

    def text_edited(self, widget, path, text):
        self.liststore[path][1] = text

win = CellRendererTextWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Need help to render the text from Right to Left in the Tree View

Comment: What is the exact problem? How the  text is _rendered_ or how it is _aligned_?

Comment: So currently the text in the ListStore is aligned from left to right. The problem is that I want the text to align from right to left which is not happening. I am trying to align the text with this marker '\u200f' which ideally align the text from right to left

Comment: You try to align text right and \u200f ideally solves the problem, what's the question? You want to align text without this symbol?

Comment: So the question is the marker '\u200f' is not working at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set a `CellRenderer`'s property directly, like you do in commented lines. Instead, you set `TreeColumn`'s attribute, which tells renderer, **where it can get value for property**. Thus, you should add extra fields in your liststore and put `xalign` value there.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Pango

class CellRendererTextWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="CellRendererText Example")

        self.set_default_size(200, 200)
        a = u'<span lang="he" foreground="black">abc \u05d1\u05d5\u05d0\u05d5 \u05d9\u05d7\u05d3 \u05d0\u05e8\u05d5\u05d7\u05ea \u05e6\u05d4\u05e8\u05d9\u05d9\u05dd</span>\u202c'

        self.liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str, str, float, str)

        treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.liststore)

        renderer_text = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        column_text = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("text", renderer_text)
        column_text.add_attribute (renderer_text, "markup", 0)
        column_text.add_attribute(renderer_text, "xalign", 2)
        column_text.add_attribute(renderer_text, "background", 3)
        treeview.append_column(column_text)


        rend_editable = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        rend_editable.set_property("editable", True)

        column_editabletext = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Editable Text", rend_editable)
        column_editabletext.add_attribute(rend_editable, "text", 1)
        treeview.append_column(column_editabletext)

        rend_editable.connect("edited", self.text_edited)

        textview = Gtk.TextView()
        textbuffer = textview.get_buffer()
        textbuffer.set_text(a)

        self.liststore.append(["Test", a, 1.0, "white"])
        self.liststore.append([a, "http://fedoraproject.org/", 1.0, "red"])
        self.liststore.append(["Slackware" * 6, "http://www.slackware.com/", 0.5, "green"])
        self.liststore.append(["Sidux", "http://sidux.com/", 0.5, "blue"])

        self.add(treeview)

    def text_edited(self, widget, path, text):
        self.liststore[path][1] = text

win = CellRendererTextWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

---

tested only on python 3